# Javascript - dependency injection?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to create a new object then call various methods against it. The idea is simply to group the code and make it tidier rather than have separate methods, all with the same required parameter.

In C# this would be easy - just a case of declaring a new instance of a class and passing the object into the constructor, but I'm unsure about how to go about this in javascript - if it's possible at all. Here's a visual (non working):

```
let wrapperMethods = function ($wrapper) {
    let isOkay = function () {
        return $wrapper.is("is something");
    };
    // more functions
};

// Initiate and call
let $wrapper2 = wrapperMethods($wrapper);
if ($wrapper2.isOkay()) {
    alert("is okay");
}
```

As you can see, there's a bit of jquery ($wrapper) in there too.

Of course, this may not be the correct approach at all. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I made your code work. But I'm a bit confused what you're really asking. Following-up question is welcome.

Comment: I could keep adding more and more functions all accepting the parameter $wrapper, but this seems like a bit of a messy approach. The idea is just to keep the code as tidy as it can be.

Comment: Do you want `class ChildClass extend BaseClass` ?

Comment: or `class SomeClass { constructor(service) { this.service = service } }`, both are valid syntax in JS.

Comment: Not 1, but 2. I want to perform a number of queries actions on my $wrapper object. As I said, I could create standalone functions and this would work, but it seems like a bit of an "amateurish" approach. So, instead I'm trying to find out if there's a better practice for grouping these functions. The example i gave was just a way of trying to explain better.

Comment: I feel we're in an XY problem situation. Perhaps a more realistic example will help ppl better understand your intention. I don't think this approach is amateurish. As of the current make-up $wrapper problem, I don't think we can further reduce code.

Comment: I wan't saying that the example I gave was amateurish or the answer you gave me. I was referring to just creating lots of independent functions.

Comment: Yeah I get it. And my answer is no. I just don’t see how we can further reduce code (or number of independent functions) **without** knowledge about things they share in common. Thus I say a more realistic example would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code copies the input instance and inject the function with no modification in the original instance.

```
let wrapperMethods = function ($wrapper) {
    let isOkay = function () {
        return $wrapper.is("is something");
        // note that you can use `this` like so: this.is("is something")
    };
    Object.assign(
        Object.create(
          Object.getPrototypeOf($wrapper).constructor
        ),
        $wrapper,
        {isOkay /*, other function names */}
     )

    // more functions
    return 
};

// Initiate and call
let $wrapper2 = wrapperMethods($wrapper);
if ($wrapper2.isOkay()) {
    alert("is okay");
}
```

If you don't need to preserve the original instance you can inject the method in the class just like the following

```
let wrapperMethods = function ($wrapper) {
    $wrapper.isOkay = function () {
        return $wrapper.is("is something");
       // same as above, you can use this.is("is something")
    }

    // more functions
    return 
};
```

If you need to inject properties or functions in the constructor of an object, then you can do the following

```
class MyReciver {
  constructor(method){
    this.method = method
  }
}
$wrapper = new MyReciver(function() {alert('ok')})
```

If you don't need the `this` reference you can also use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: These are both great, but what I was thinking of from the outset was the second example. I think that's my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're so close, just return the `{ isOkay }` as an object.

```js
let wrapperMethods = function ($wrapper) {
    let isOkay = function () {
        return $wrapper.is("is something");
    };

    let isNotOkay = function () {
        return !$wrapper.is("is something");
    };    
    
    return { isOkay, isNotOkay }
};

// Initiate and call
let $wrapper2 = wrapperMethods($wrapper);
if ($wrapper2.isOkay()) {
    alert("is okay");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. In taking the approach above (returning okay), does that limit me to only returning isOkay? Different methods are likely to have different return params and some may not return anything.

Comment: No, just updated. You can return multiple things, or nothing at all.